# HTML checkbox change value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, html, database, ajax, checkbox

I have a checkbox and I need that when it is "checked" to alter a [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) Table value to "yes" and if it's checked when you uncheck to "no".

I want to accomplish this with [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Use [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) and PHP.

This is [an example](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype) in jQuery:

```
 $.post("test.php", { isChecked:$('#checkbox_id').attr('checked') } );
```

This statement should be defined at either in the `<head></head>`, or in a separate JavaScript file.

And in your PHP code you can check for the `isChecked` `POST` variable:

```
if($_POST('isChecked')==1)
{
  //Set MySQL table to 1.
}
else
{
  //Set MySQL table to 0.
}
```

Here is [a reference on how to use post](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp). And here's [how you can use PHP to update MySQL table](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp).

Comment: Thank you for your example. Ill try implement it.

Comment: I have a doubt the jquery part, is that code included in each check box tag ex: <input (jquery code)> or is it a generic statement that's triggered each time a check box is ticked?

Comment: It's a generic statement; you should define it either in the `<head></head>`, or in a separate js file

Comment: Hi, could you please take a look at the post i just made? Thank you.

Comment: You have an error in your code. It should be $_POST['isChecked']

Answer (score 1):

You use the checkbox's onchange event handler to issue an XmlHttpRequest to some server-side code to update your table.

Comment: Thank you, could you please provide some reference?